# How to use query (or modify table) in Redshift as event to trigger AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Basically here I want to send a notification to AWS SNS when my target table in Redshift cluster modified (for example I load new data from S3 to this table).

But When I went through Redshift documents, the events are all at higher level(like cluster, security group), and more concern about system management, monitoring and error.

So I was wondering is there a way to use specific Redshift table as an event to trigger AWS SNS?